# Integral maxima and minima of multivariable polynomial

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am getting the function $$f(x_1,\dots,x_k) = \sum_{i=1}^k(x_i)(x_i-1) + \sum_{1 \le i < j \le k}x_i x_j g(i,j)$$  where $g(i, j)$ is bounded by some $m \in \mathbb N$,
subject to sum of the $x_i$ being equal to a fixed number $n$,
as an answer to a counting problem where $x_1,\dots,x_k$ are positve integer inputs of the problem.

How to understand the maximum and minimum of the function $f$ in $\mathbb N^k$?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. $(x_1,\ldots,x_k) \in \{(x_1,\ldots,x_k) \in \mathbb{N}^k \colon x_1+\ldots+x_k = n\}$, a finite set. What is the problem?

Comment: Your finite set is lattice points in the polytope $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$. The domain of the function $f$ is this polytope. How to find the maximum and minimum of this function $f$ in this polytope?